# D3 Js with Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, d3

I am Creating a Customize Chart using D3.Js 
I am able see the graph with Static data as a given in example
But I am not aware of how to bind data dynamically

Here is My Code

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController"  docType="html-5.0"         applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">  
 <html>
<head>
  <!-- Load c3.css -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
<script>
 var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#chart',
 data:
 {
 columns:
  [

    ['data1', 50, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95,100],
    ['data2',  50, 20, 40, 30, 45, 55,70],
    ['data3', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25,30],
    ['data4',30,40,20,50,40,60,80]
          ]
     }
  });
</script>
</html>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Chart">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pieData}" var="c">
         <apex:column headerValue="NUM" value="{!c.num}"/>
         <apex:column  headerValue="RemainingPercentage"
          value="{!c.data}"/>
         <apex:column headerValue="API" value="{!c.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:page>
```

In the above code I would like to Replace the data1....data4 and their corresponding values
I am able to print the data in apex:pageblock table in the formate i need
Reference to the D3 Examples:http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html#setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple, but incomplete, answer is that you'd use visualforce expression syntax just like you would use anywhere else. `{!expression}` is evaluated on the server, before the page itself is rendered.

If your controller had the following property in it

```
public String myData {set;}
```

and, in your controller, you explicitly define a getter method

```
public String getMyData(){
    if(myData == null){
        myData = '["data1", 50, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95,100],["data2",  50, 20, 40, 30, 45, 55,70],["data3", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25,30],["data4",30,40,20,50,40,60,80]';
    }

    return myData;
}
```

then you could use visualforce expression syntax to bind your data more dynamically

```
<script>
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data:
        {
            columns:
            [
                // JSON.parse() is required here because the JSON returned by
                //   {!myData} is (and can only be) a string
                JSON.parse({!myData})
            ]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Conceptually, from there, the only missing piece of the puzzle is *how do I take the data I have in my controller, and generate JSON from it?*

You haven't provided your controller, so you'll need to work out the exact details yourself (even if you did provide your controller, I wouldn't code everything for you. Copy/pasting is a much less effective teacher than struggling with coding it yourself is).

I can, however, provide some hints to get you going:

- `JSON.serialize()` in apex is your friend
- Having an array with mixed data types makes things a bit more complicated. You won't be able to use a simple `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`. A `List<Object>` should work, though.
- You're probably better off making a `List<List<Object>>`, and plugging that into your javascript like `... columns: JSON.Parse({!myData})`
- Look at your current Visualforce to give you hints about how your apex should look. For example,`<apex:pageBlockTable>` iterates over a collection in Visualforce, and that would translate to a `for` loop in Apex